# Ошибка в TileRule Unity выход за пределы массива

Tags: c#, unity3d

'''

```
private static void RuleMatrixOnGUI(Rect rect, RuleTile.TilingRule tilingRule) 
{ 
Handles.color = EditorGUIUtility.isProSkin ? new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.2f) : new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.2f); 
int index = 0; 
float w = rect.width / 3f; 
float h = rect.height / 3f; 

for (int y = 0; y <= 3; y++) 
{ 
float top = rect.yMin + y * h; 
Handles.DrawLine(new Vector3(rect.xMin, top), new Vector3(rect.xMax, top)); 
} 
for (int x = 0; x <= 3; x++) 
{ 
float left = rect.xMin + x * w; 
Handles.DrawLine(new Vector3(left, rect.yMin), new Vector3(left, rect.yMax)); 
} 
Handles.color = Color.white; 

for (int y = 0; y <= 2; y++) 
{ 
for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++) 
{ 
Rect r = new Rect(rect.xMin + x * w, rect.yMin + y * h, w - 1, h - 1); 
if (x != 1 || y != 1) 
{ 
switch (tilingRule.m_Neighbors[index]) 
{ 
case RuleTile.TilingRule.Neighbor.This: 
GUI.DrawTexture(r, arrows[y*3 + x]); 
break; 
case RuleTile.TilingRule.Neighbor.NotThis: 
GUI.DrawTexture(r, arrows[9]); 
break; 
} 
if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDown && r.Contains(Event.current.mousePosition)) 
{ 
int change = 1; 
if (Event.current.button == 1) 
change = -1; 
//if (index < tilingRule.m_Neighbors.Count) 
//{ 
tilingRule.m_Neighbors[index] = (((int)tilingRule.m_Neighbors[index] + change) % 3); 
//} 
//Debug.Log(tilingRule.m_Neighbors[index]); 

GUI.changed = true; 
Event.current.Use(); 
} 
//(RuleTile.TilingRule.m_Neighbors) 
index++; 
} 
   else 
{ 
switch (tilingRule.m_RuleTransform) 
{ 
case RuleTile.TilingRule.Transform.Rotated: 
GUI.DrawTexture(r, autoTransforms[0]); 
break; 
case RuleTile.TilingRule.Transform.MirrorX: 
GUI.DrawTexture(r, autoTransforms[1]); 
break; 
case RuleTile.TilingRule.Transform.MirrorY: 
GUI.DrawTexture(r, autoTransforms[2]); 
break; 
} 

if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDown && r.Contains(Event.current.mousePosition)) 
{ 
tilingRule.m_RuleTransform = (RuleTile.TilingRule.Transform)(((int)tilingRule.m_RuleTransform + 1) % 4); 
GUI.changed = true; 
Event.current.Use(); 
} 
} 
} 
} 
}
'''
```

00000000000000000000000
tilingRule.m_Neighbors[index] = (((int)tilingRule.m_Neighbors[index] + change) % 3);
на эту строку выдаёт 5 ошибок
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
как от них избавиться

Comment: Что должен делать ваш код?

Comment: Хотя бы табуляции поправьте, невозможно же код читать.